# Tail bounds for maximum of Laplace random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose there are $n$ IID random variables denoted as $X=(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$, they follow Laplace distribution with parameter $\lambda$, denoted as $\operatorname{Lap}(\lambda)$. That is,
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}\right)
$$
Let $M=\max(X)$, since Laplace variables are not sub-gaussian, instead sub-exponential, I am not sure how we can get the tail bound of $M$.

---

Update: I just found one possible solution, you can help me check.
$$P(\max_{i\in[n]} X_i\geq \lambda \ln M) = P(\exists i \in [n], X_i \geq \lambda \ln M) \leq \sum_{i\in [n]}P(X_i\geq\lambda\ln M) \leq \frac{n}{2M}$$

The first inequality uses the union bound, and the second inequality uses the tail bound of the Laplace variable, i.e., $P(|Z| \geq \lambda \ln M) \leq \frac{1}{M}$, for $Z\sim Lap(\lambda)$.

I am not sure if there are tighter or more general bounds.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda=1$ then
$
P(\max_i X_i>t+\log n)=1-(1-\frac{1}{2n}e^{-t})^n\to_{n\to\infty} 1- e^{-\frac12 e^{-t}}.
$

If $\lambda\ne 1$ consider $Y_i=X_i/\lambda$ instead.

Similar questions would be more suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ next time.